# ruby commands are not working on my terminal

Tags: ruby

so i have recently decided to try and learn ruby. i have a windows 10 hp laptop using git bash (ruby 2.7.1p83) and sublime text editor 3.
i have only made it into week 2 of my ruby intro class but it seems like my computer and the language are  not working together.

this is the process;

- open git bash
- type `irb`
- about 2-3 seconds nothing happens then the next line on git bash puts

```
switch to inspect mode
krisb@laptop MINGW64 
$ irb
SWITCH TO INSPECT MODE
puts hello world
puts hello world
NameError (undefined local variable or method `world' for main:Object)
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.3/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
```

if i close out git bash and use the 'winpty' it just sits after I input the command.

```
krisb@laptop MINGW64
$ alias irb='winpty "$(which irb).cmd"' 
>puts hello world [hit enter(moves to next line)]
>
```

Comment: You're going to have a hard time developing in Ruby on Windows, you best option is switching to a Unix based system (either completely, with dual boot or a Virtual machine) or take a look into [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

Comment: Use Cygwin with Ruby installed within it, not git-bash.

Comment: Your first approach seems to work fine. The error you get is because you have not quoted your strings (i.e. you likely want to write `puts "hello world"` instead). In general though, while Windows is supported by Ruby, most people use Linux or macOS instead. Thus, you might sometimes run into minor roadblocks on Windows. You might have an easier time with the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) which gives you an Ubuntu setup inside your existing Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `git-bash` gives you the appearance of a Unix terminal environment under Windows which can be handy if you are doing a tutorial targeted at Linux or Mac users, but it has its limitations. Have a look at RubyInstaller (https://rubyinstaller.org/about/comparison/) as it seems to be the closest thing to an official port of Ruby for Windows, and seems to be fairly self-contained and not have too many other dependencies.